# Syntax error when passing method argument in link_to in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, link-to

When I put :method => :delete in link_to I'm getting syntax error and I don't understand why. 
Here's the code:

```
  <%= link_to application_path(application), :method => :delete, :confirm => 'Are you sure?', :title => 'Delete task', :class => "color-red" do %>
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash">
  <% end %>
```

Comment: link_to "some name", application_path(application), :method => :delete,...

Comment: @RailsOuter that's what the `do` block does.

Comment: @Madalina there's no obvious syntax error in your code, can you show the syntax error itself, and tell us precisely which line the error is on in your file.